# PostGIS ST_AsGeoJSON throws error

Tags: postgis, geojson

I'm inserting Open Street Map data into a PostGIS database using the [GeometryBuilder](http://javadoc.topobyte.de/osm4j/de/topobyte/osm4j/geometry/GeometryBuilder.html) of [osm4j](http://jaryard.com/projects/osm4j/). I then fetch the data and display it on a Leaflet map using [ST_AsGeoJSON](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html).

This usually works flawlessly, but every now and then PostGIS throws an exception at me. For example, [OSM relation 13169](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/13169) does not work:

```
select ST_GeometryType(geom) from featuretable where id=13169;
    st_geometrytype    
-----------------------
 ST_GeometryCollection
(1 row)

select ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) from featuretable where id=13169;
ERROR:  GeoJson: geometry not supported.
```

Doing `select ST_AsBinary(geom) from featuretable where id=13169;` gives [this](https://pastebin.pl/view/233eef32) output.

At first I thought that features of type `ST_GeometryCollection` could not be handled by `ST_AsGeoJSON`, but for instance [OSM relation 3244259](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/3244259) works fine and is also a `ST_GeometryCollection`.

```
select ST_GeometryType(geom) from featuretable where id=3244259;
    st_geometrytype    
-----------------------
 ST_GeometryCollection
```

What is it that makes `ST_AsGeoJSON` crash on certain features, and how can I prevent it? All I really want is a GeoJSON of the feature; perhaps it is possible to convert/transform the feature somehow to achieve this?

Comment: Possible 'Winding' issue (Polygon direction of arrays) see https://macwright.com/2015/03/23/geojson-second-bite.html#multi-geometries for the right-hand rule.

Comment: fyi In the past have had issues with compound curves (arcs) from autocad sourced data to geojson.  Your error states "geometry not supported" so it will need to be fixed (or omitted)

Comment: Please `ST_AsBinary` us that failing geometry to test.

Comment: @geozelot: I have uploaded it [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/233eef32) (and updated the question)

Comment: Could you edit the title of the question? PostGIS does not crash, it just throws an error. That seems to be intentional with As_GeoJSON and the geometry that it gets.

Comment: @user30184: Changed. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GeoJSON specification warns about nested GeometryCollections in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#page-9

> To maximize interoperability, implementations SHOULD avoid nested
> GeometryCollections.

The failing GeometryCollection begins like this when queried with `ST_AsText`

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY,MULTILINESTRING((1....
```

Thus it is a nested GeometryCollection and PostGIS does not convert that into GeoJSON. Test with a simple nested GeometryCollection yields the same error.

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(
ST_GeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION ( GEOMETRYCOLLECTION ( POINT ( 505 396 )), GEOMETRYCOLLECTION ( POINT ( 566 406 )))'));

ERROR:  GeoJson: geometry not supported.
SQL state: XX000
```

I do not know if nested GeometryCollections are OK for OSM. Anyway, removing the empty GeometryCollection from the OSM relation should be fine.